# CSS on hover show content

Tags: html, css

I'm kicking myself here as I've done this plenty of times before, but for some reason my code is not working and I can't workout why. I've been staring at it for a while now so that probably doesn't help. Anyway I'm trying to do a CSS on hover. So when you hover over a div with it displays another div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="pressListItem">
   <img src="" width="" height="">
   <h3>July 2013</h3>
</div>
<div class="pressItemHover">
   <p>This is come more content, lalala here is a little snippet</p>
   <span></span>
   <span>Read more</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

I'm using the opacity transition as I want it fade in.

```
.pressItemHover{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear 0s;
    visibility: hidden; 
}

.pressListItem:hover .pressItemHover{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.pressListItem{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right:12px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px #e4e4e4;      
}
```

If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the selector to:

```
.pressListItem:hover + .pressItemHover {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BZLG5/)**

`.pressListItem:hover .pressItemHover` looks for an element with the class `pressItemHover` that is a descendant of `pressListItem` when in reality it's a sibling, in which case you want to use the adjacent sibling selector `+`.

Comment: 1+ It works, but it's really glitchy.. It flickers - in Chrome anyways

Comment: Perfect thank you! I even tried using the > but the + seems to have done the trick! Thank you!!

Comment: @JoshC ok thanks, i'll do some testing, probably need to play with the CSS

Comment: `>` is the child (immediate descendant) selector, so that wouldn't have worked either (as you saw).

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML `.pressListItem` and `.pressItemHover` are *siblings*. In your CSS you're defining styles to a `div` which is a *child* of `.pressListItem`. You need to change HTML to this

```
<div class="pressListItem">
    <img src="" width="" height="">
    <h3>July 2013</h3>

    <div class="pressItemHover">
        <p>This is come more content, lalala here is a little snippet</p>
        <span></span>
        <span>Read more</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

or if you don't wan't to restructure your DOM you can just change this part of CSS

```
.pressListItem:hover + .pressItemHover {
```