# HTML show more text on hover

Tags: html, css

First of all, I know this question was already asked and answered here: [CSS on hover show content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188243/css-on-hover-show-content)

But for some reason, it simply ISN'T working for me! So frustrating... I'll try and keep it brief.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li class="servicesfin"><a href=" ">Financial Advising</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="servicesfindesc">
   <p>Offshore Bank accounts, money laundering, hedge funds, tax evasion, investing.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.servicesfindesc {
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}

.servicesfin:hover + .servicesfindesc {
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: `+` I don't think will get to `.servicesfindesc` because it is inside the `ul`

Comment: And by the way, could I change some of these classes to ID's and the selectors/siblings would still work just fine?

Comment: Yes, you can interchange classes and IDs all you want.  `.servicesfin:hover + .servicesfindesc` is the same as `#servicesfin:hover + #servicesfindesc` or `.servicesfin:hover + #servicesfindesc`.  HOWEVER, IDs are for UNIQUE items, do not confuse that.  If you need to use it more than once, use a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move class to `<ul>` to make `+` (adjacent sibling selector) work.

```css
.servicesfindesc {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.servicesfin:hover + .servicesfindesc {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul class="floatleft servicesfin">
   <li><a href=" ">Financial Advising</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="servicesfindesc">
   <p>Offshore Bank accounts, money laundering, hedge funds, tax evasion, investing.</p>
</div>
```

If you want to select all next siblings you could use `~` (general sibling selector).

```css
.servicesfindesc {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.servicesfin:hover ~ .servicesfindesc {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul class="floatleft servicesfin">
   <li><a href=" ">Financial Advising</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="servicesfindesc">
   <p>Offshore Bank accounts, money laundering, hedge funds, tax evasion, investing.</p>
</div>
<div class="servicesfindesc">
   <p>Offshore Bank accounts, money laundering, hedge funds, tax evasion, investing.</p>
</div>
<div class="servicesfindesc">
   <p>Offshore Bank accounts, money laundering, hedge funds, tax evasion, investing.</p>
</div>
<div class="servicesfindesc">
   <p>Offshore Bank accounts, money laundering, hedge funds, tax evasion, investing.</p>
</div>
```

Reference: [Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) - [General sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

Comment: What if I have multiple li's in the ul?

Comment: You have to change your html structure then.

Comment: You have to add `<div>` elements inside `<li>` then.

Comment: So instead of using ul's I could just turn the li's into div's and style them the same as li's so everything would share a common parent?

Comment: But that wouldn't be ideal for accessibility... But you're saying I should do `<li><div class="servicesfin">Financial Services</div></li>`

Comment: You could add: `<li><a href=" " class="servicesfin">Financial Advising</a><p class="servicesfindesc"> ... </p></li>`.

Comment: So what if I have another li that is called "Technology" and I want it to show different text but in the same spot, replacing the text brought up by hovering over the li "Financial Advising"? I can only see your solution solving a single or 2 identical li scenario

Comment: With css you could target only siblings and childs, you can't target parent elements.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using the `+` selector in CSS which indicates an adjacent element in the HTML.  If you move the DIV alongside your LI then it will work, although it's not proper HTML, I just want to show you since you are using the `+`.

Like so:
http://jsfiddle.net/scottcanoni/tsyndeuj/2/

```
<ul class="floatleft">
   <li class="servicesfin"><a href=" ">Financial Advising</a></li>
    <div class="servicesfindesc">
       <p>Offshore Bank accounts, money laundering, hedge funds, tax evasion, investing.</p>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Related: [What does the `+` mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean)

Comment: This won't quite work for my situation I don't think. I have other li's split into 2 columns on the page, with the "servicesfindesc" appearing in the middle between them.

Comment: Then you are forced to use javascript to change the visibility of other sections of the HTML that can't be selected solely via CSS.  You can add a JS mouseover/mouseout function which shows/hides the other HTML.

Comment: Alright, well I don't need to stick with using +, that's just what I saw used on the other page I referenced. I guess I need to read up on css siblings... Thanks for the link!

Comment: Here is an example that uses JS to control the visibility of the other HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/scottcanoni/tsyndeuj/

Answer (score -2):

Remove visibility: visible and visibility: hidden; dont need

```
.servicesfindesc {
    opacity: 0;

}
.servicesfin:hover  {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I was going to use the display: block / display: none, but I was told that's not good practice for SEO. Does visibility/opacity still show text for search engines?

Comment: This doesn't work, or at least doesn't solve the issue