# How To Have More Links Appear While Hovering On One

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am making a website, and one of the features I would like it to have is that when a user hovers over a piece of text, more links appear like this:

```
     More (hovered on)
     Pizza (link)
     Burgers (link)
     Fries (link)
```

I was thinking that I could possibly use CSS to make the links white (the website has a white screen, no background) when not hovered on and black when hovered on, but what if someone clicked the link without realizing????

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML show more text on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366458/html-show-more-text-on-hover)

Comment: Does the question I showed help you?

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution assuming it's alright that the links are children of the div you want to hover over.

```css
a {
  display: none;
}
p:hover a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  More
  <a href="#">Pizza</a>
  <a href="#">Burgers</a>
  <a href="#">Fries</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

improving on ssbear's answer :

```css
p {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

p a:first-of-type {
display: block;
}

a {
  display: none;
}

p:hover a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">More</a>
  <a href="#">Pizza</a>
  <a href="#">Burgers</a>
  <a href="#">Fries</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fine if you follow the above answers. But if you want to keep all list item tag then A simple javascript code is fine to do what you want.

```js
let more = document.querySelector(".more");
let hide = document.querySelectorAll(".hide");
more.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  for (i = 0; i < hide.length; i++) {
    hide[i].style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="more"><a href="#"> More (hovered on)</a></li>

  <li class="hide"><a href="#">Pizza (link) </a></li>
  <li class="hide"><a href="#">Burgers (link)</a></li>
  <li class="hide"><a href="#">Fries (link)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: As a general rule, if something can be fully accomplished with css, go with css (... well, especially in a traditionnal/frameworkless approach).